# "import time" and "from datetime import time" together?

Tags: python, datetime, time

I have a piece of code in my `view.py` that works if I use `from datetime import time`:

Working Code:

```
from datetime import time, ...

times = []
for i in range(0, 24*4):
    times.append((datetime.combine(date.today(), 
    time()) + timedelta(minutes=15) * i).time().strftime("%I:%M %p"))
```

Unfortunately, if I have that in place, I have another code in my `view.py` that is using `import time` to convert am/pm time to 24h db friendly format that will not work if the `from datetime import time` is in place.

Code:

```
import time 

mytime = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.strptime(mytime, '%I:%M %p'))
```

So the questions are:

1. is there any workaround to have both imports in place?
2. If not, how can I make the first function to work with `import time`?
3. Is there anther way to convert from am/pm to 24h format using `import datetime`?

Comment: The `.time()` in `.time().strftime(...)` is reduntant. Just use `strftime()` directly on the `datetime` object.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using `datetime.combine(date.today(), time())` when `datetime.now()` would do...

Comment: `now, quarter = datetime.now(), timedelta(minutes=15)`, then `times = [(now + quarter * i).strftime('%I:%M %p') for i in range(24 * 4)]` gets you the same output.

Comment: Your other snippet can just as well be expressed as `datetime.strptime(mytime, '%I:%M %p').strftime('%H:%M:%S')`, removing the need to import the `time` module altogether.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Unfortunately, I cant be using `datetime.now()` as I need even times for the my appointment times such as 2pm 2:15pm, 2:30pm etc. Any suggestions how I can use the `now, quarter = ...` option without the `now`?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean, you need today, midnight. You could use `datetime.now().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)`, or indeed, the `datetime.combine(date.today(), time.min)`. I forgot that `time()` produces midnight, mea culpa.

Comment: Where does `mytime` come? Are you by any chance generate time strings in am/pm format only to parse them immediately back? (don't do it, work with `datetime` objects instead). Here're [@MartijnPieters' suggestions combined](http://ideone.com/dsgx2j).

Comment: mytime comes from a web form as a string `mytime = request.POST['mytime']`

Comment: The issue now is that my django form is not validating the time string from `datetime.strptime(mytime, '%I:%M %p').strftime('%H:%M:%S'` as a valid time even though it has been converted to `HH:MM:SS` format, any suggestions on that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`import` is a variable assignment, and you can't have two variables with the same name in the same scope.

What you *can* do is just use `datetime` as a module.

```
import datetime
import time

datetime.time()
```

You could also use `datetime.datetime.strptime` instead of `time.strptime`, and avoid the `time` module altogether.

Comment: thank you for the feedback. When I made the change I get `type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Either `from datetime import datetime; datetime.strptime()` or `import datetime; datetime.datetime.strptime()`.

Answer (score 5):

You could try `from datetime import time as dtime`.

Comment: note that this can be a little confusing, since aliasing is unusual and the reader may not expect `dtime` to refer to a stdlib type.

Comment: Oh, you're absolutely right.  I wouldn't actually do it that way, it's just an example of how you might import two same-name modules without a conflict.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion! I think it would also be a valid option!

Answer (score 1):

`datetime.time` class is used relatively rare compared to `time` module therefore you could use a longer name for it:

```
import time
from datetime import time as datetime_time
```

Answer (score -1):

or just use

```
import time

time.sleep()
time.time()
```